# PartAlreadyExistsException when reading POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to read an Excel file (xlsx) that has 19455 row. I am using last version of POI. When my app comes to ;

```
    FileInputStreaminputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

these rows getting PartAlreadyExistException. Also writing the error console;

A part with the name '/xl/sharedStrings.xml' already exists : Packages shall not contain equivalent part names and package implementers shall neither create nor recognize packages with equivalent part names. [M1.12]

Why I can't read this excel file?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? If it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I am using poi 3.17

Comment: Can you provide the file that fails in the apache poin issue tracker [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI).

Comment: If you open the file in excel, and do a save-as, does that fix it?

Comment: When I do save-as It resolved. But this excel file coming to me other place and I have to read them automatically by job.

Comment: I wonder is excel format wrong? Also I have report the bug to apache bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the excel corrupted or not...
I was getting same Exception, when i debugged I found ou

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).